# Error al invocar o llamar un componente en App de React Native: Error: undefined Unable to resolve module, None of these files exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, component, importación, exists

Ya probé todas las formas de export-import para functional component que hay. Cambié la extensión del componente que estoy creando y tratando de renderizar de jsx a js. Intenté cambiando la extencion de App.js a App.jsx.
Utilicé fragmento y también View para envolver el componente en el return de App. Y en todos los casos me sigue crasheando cuando escribo el componente dentro del return de App.

También probé crear una app nueva de react native con `npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject` creando un nuevo componente y llamarlo en App. En direfentes carpetas dentro de mi disco duro. Y nada parece funcionar.

---

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./src/screens/LoadingScreen from D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\App.js:

None of these files exist:
  * src\screens\LoadingScreen(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * src\screens\LoadingScreen\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  1 | import React from 'react';
  2 | import { Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
> 3 | import { LoadingScreen } from './src/screens/LoadingScreen';
    |                                ^
  4 |
  5 | const App = () => {
  6 |
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:107:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at Object.resolve (D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (D:\FLOR\DISENO-WEB\React Native\TestOne\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
```

---

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export const LoadingScreen = () => {
    return (
        <>
        
        <View>
            <Text>Loading Screen</Text>
        </View>
        </>
    )
}
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import { LoadingScreen } from './src/screens/LoadingScreen'

const App = () => {

  

  return (
    <>
      <LoadingScreen/>
     
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

[image: Carpetas y archivos]

Comment: Si tu archivo App.js esta dentro del folder `src`, intenta lo siguiente `import { LoadingScreen } from './screens/LoadingScreen'`, estoy asumiendo que el folder `screens` también esta dentro de `src`;

Comment: Hola, mi archivo App.js esta en la carpeta raíz, que lleva el nombre de la aplicación, a la misma altura que src

Comment: bien, logré reproducir el error en [snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev/);  intenta dejar la extension `js` para ambos `App.js` y `LoadingScreen.js` puede que eso funcione.

Comment: Funcionó!! Muchas gracias!!!